# How can I extend this AngularJS filter to sort alphabetically by object property?

Tags: javascript, angularjs, sorting

I have an array of objects called `cases`, with 3 methods of sorting: by length of case.keywords, or alphabetically by case.reason or case.category. The selected sort order is stored on $scope.currentSort, which is switched with a select drop-down.

Here is my filter so far, which reads the value of $scope.currentSort and calls the relevant sort function. It currently works for the default/keyword sort. All the console.logs are triggered when expected.

How do I return an alphabetical sort for the Reason & Category sorts?

```
.filter('orderBySelected', function() {

   function compareKeywords(a, b) {
   //Sorts by length of array keywords

    if (a.keywords && b.keywords) {
        if (a.keywords.length < b.keywords.length)
            return 1;
        if (a.keywords.length > b.keywords.length)
            return -1;
        return 0;
    } else if (a.keywords && !b.keywords) {
        return -1;
    } else {
        return 1;
    }

  }

  function compareReason(a, b) {
    //What do I put here to sort alphabetically by property .reason?
  }

return function (input, currentSort) {
//Input is all the cases. Check which sort is desired based on value of currentSort: 

    if (currentSort.value == 1) {
        console.log("Current sort is default :" + currentSort.name)
        return input.sort(compareKeywords); //calls that sorting method above

    } else if (currentSort.value == 2) {
        console.log("Current sort is Reason: " + currentSort.name)
        return input.sort(compareReason)

    } else if (currentSort.value == 3) {
        console.log("Current sort is Category: " + currentSort.name)
    }



}
});
```

Answer (score 0):

This works:

```
 function compareReason(a, b) {

    if (a.reason && b.reason) {
        var nameA=a.reason.toLowerCase(), nameB=b.reason.toLowerCase()

        if (nameA < nameB) //sort string ascending
            return -1
        if (nameA > nameB)
            return 1
        return 0 //default return value (no sorting)
    } else if (a.reason && !b.reason) {
        return -1;
    } else {
        return 1;
    }

}
```